# javascript - show match item onkeyup

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

this one already works, but I have a problem on changing the content of the array.

I wanted to query on my database and use that data as an element of my array.

how can I do that guys?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function ShowMe(obj) {

            var lbl = document.getElementById('divContent');

            var myArray = new Array();
            myArray[0] = "Football";
            myArray[1] = "Baseball";
            myArray[2] = "Cricket";
            myArray[3] = "Fast";

            var s2 = obj.value.toLowerCase();

            for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                if (myArray[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(s2) != -1) 
                {
                    lbl.innerHTML = myArray[i];
                }
            }

        }

    </script>


<div>
<h1>JS Test</h1>
<input id="txtInput" onkeyup="javascript:ShowMe(this)" />
<div id="divContent">

</div>
```

the main problem is... how can I pass my array into the script?

let say I already have

```
$myquery_array;
```

Comment: http://jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try reading about [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: For pass the array into script the best practice is AJAX, if you don't know JavaScript, try to use jQuery, it's simple. You call a PHP that returns the PHP array and saves in JavaScript array. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I tried to copy paste the code on the link you provided (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), I copied it as it is but nothings happen. Is there anything that I need to add?